# How to load quads using the bulk loader?

Tags: blazegraph

I have a file `data.nq` containing the following lines:

```
<http://example.org/a> <http://example.org/b> <http://example.org/c> .
<http://example.org/d> <http://example.org/e> <http://example.org/f> <http://example.org/g> .
```

In the same directory, there is `blazegraph.jar` (using version 2.1.0) and a file `p.properties` with the following content:

```
com.bigdata.btree.BTree.branchingFactor=512
com.bigdata.btree.writeRetentionQueue.capacity=4000
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.bufferMode=DiskRW
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.file=blazegraph.jnl
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.initialExtent=209715200
com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.maximumExtent=209715200
com.bigdata.namespace.kb.spo.com.bigdata.btree.BTree.branchingFactor=1024
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.truthMaintenance=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.axiomsClass=com.bigdata.rdf.axioms.NoAxioms
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.justify=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=true
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.statementIdentifiers=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.textIndex=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader.commit=Incremental
com.bigdata.service.AbstractTransactionService.minReleaseAge=1
```

Then, I run the [bulk loader](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/Bulk_Data_Load) with the following command:

```
java -cp blazegraph.jar com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader p.properties data.nq
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Reading properties: p.properties
Will load from: data.nq
Journal file: blazegraph.jnl
ERROR: SPORelation.java:2303: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context not bound: < TermId(1U), TermId(2U), TermId(3U) : Expli
cit >
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context not bound: < TermId(1U), TermId(2U), TermId(3U) : Explicit >
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPORelation.logFuture(SPORelation.java:2298)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPORelation.insert(SPORelation.java:2253)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.addStatements(AbstractTripleStore.java:4392)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$Batch.writeSPOs(StatementBuffer.java:2126)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$Batch.addStatements(StatementBuffer.java:1975)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$Batch.writeNow(StatementBuffer.java:1860)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$Batch.access$1000(StatementBuffer.java:1654)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$DrainQueueCallable.call(StatementBuffer.java:818)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$DrainQueueCallable.call(StatementBuffer.java:794)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.bigdata.util.concurrent.LatchedExecutor$1.run(LatchedExecutor.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context not bound: < TermId(1U), TermId(2U), TermId(3U) : Explicit >
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPOIndexWriter.call(SPOIndexWriter.java:266)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPOIndexWriter.call(SPOIndexWriter.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    ... 3 more
ERROR: Banner.java:160: Uncaught exception in thread
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context not bound: < TermId(1U), TermId(2U), TermId(3U) : Explicit >
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer.flush(StatementBuffer.java:954)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.PresortRioLoader.success(PresortRioLoader.java:108)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.BasicRioLoader.loadRdf2(BasicRioLoader.java:251)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.BasicRioLoader.loadRdf(BasicRioLoader.java:176)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader.loadData4_ParserErrors_Not_Trapped(DataLoader.java:1595)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader.loadFiles(DataLoader.java:1359)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader.main(DataLoader.java:2085)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context not bound: < TermId(1U), TermId(2U), TermId(3U) : Explicit >
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer.flush(StatementBuffer.java:940)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context not bound: < TermId(1U), TermId(2U), TermId(3U) : Explicit >
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPORelation.insert(SPORelation.java:2272)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.addStatements(AbstractTripleStore.java:4392)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$Batch.writeSPOs(StatementBuffer.java:2126)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$Batch.addStatements(StatementBuffer.java:1975)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$Batch.writeNow(StatementBuffer.java:1860)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$Batch.access$1000(StatementBuffer.java:1654)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$DrainQueueCallable.call(StatementBuffer.java:818)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.rio.StatementBuffer$DrainQueueCallable.call(StatementBuffer.java:794)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.bigdata.util.concurrent.LatchedExecutor$1.run(LatchedExecutor.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context not bound: < TermId(1U), TermId(2U), TermId(3U) : Explicit >
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPORelation.logFuture(SPORelation.java:2298)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPORelation.insert(SPORelation.java:2253)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: context not bound: < TermId(1U), TermId(2U), TermId(3U) : Explicit >
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPOIndexWriter.call(SPOIndexWriter.java:266)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.spo.SPOIndexWriter.call(SPOIndexWriter.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    ... 3 more
```

I do the same, but setting the quads mode off. That is, setting the following property in `p.properties`:

```
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=false
```

In this case I get no error, but also no named graphs in the dataset.

How can I load quads using the bulk loader?

**Update:** I found an explanation for this error in the [Blazegraph documentation](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/REST_API#Context_Not_Bound_Error_.28Quads_mode_without_defaultGraph.29). It says that I have to set the property `defaultGraph` in the properties file. Thus, I have added the following line to the properties file:

```
defaultGraph=http://example.org
```

However, I got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is required to add `defaultGraph` as an option in the command line, not in the properties file.

```
$ java -cp blazegraph.jar com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader -defaultGraph http://example.org p.properties data.nq
```

(Thanks to people that help me to answer this question in the Blazegraph mailing list).

Comment: I'm new to semantic data, what does the 'defaultGraph' mean, how does it relate to the imported N-Quad data?

Comment: Also, how are N-Quad's 4-columns consumed/structured within the triple store after import, i.e. is ALL the data from the 4 columns available, if so, how is it queried/structured/re-constructed from SPO-triples?

Comment: @BigRich, yo can use the SPARQL keyword `GRAPH ?g { ... }` to access the graph column in a quad dataset.